# Is EngineID configurable with snmptrapd

Tags: net-snmp

I have a SNMP trap sender, in which I have to *configure* the EngineID of the receiver (doesn't seem to support *discovery*) in case of SNMP V3 Inform!.

And my receiver being `snmptrapd`, the EngineID seems to be a random generated one on each restart (the `msgAuthoritativeEngineID`)!

I there a way to *assign* an EngineID to `snmptrapd`, so that I can configure it on the sender side?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `engineID` option, and it seems to work with `snmptrapd.conf` as well! (though its documented only in `snmpd.conf`). I.e the EngineID is same across restarts.